# Vue js Element ui dialog

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

How can I design el-dialog left-top close button? I want to change it with my own close button.

Is there any way for change it?

for example.

```
<el-dialog
  title="Tips"
  :visible.sync="dialogVisible"
  width="30%"
  :before-close="handleClose">
  <span>My custom close button</span> # my close button left top corner.

</el-dialog>
```

Comment: do you want something like [this](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/KKzGRxZ)?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim No i need **Close** text insted of **x** icon.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim thanks that is good idea. But I need Close text. There is no way for doing this, Some typescript or javascript tricks?

Comment: usually some components provide slots to customize the rendering of some parts but in this case there's no slot dedicated to close, https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dialog#slot

Comment: i could suggest a DOM manipulation using pure js but it's not a good practice

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim If it is not too difficult could you show one example!

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I can do it by selecting the original DOM and manipulate it but I need different experience.

Comment: Yes you should use a different solution because manipulating the dom using js is a very bad practice

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim  https://codepen.io/SomeOneOrAnyOne/pen/ExKdLzJ  i found it. That is enough.

Comment: Good, post that as answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is one property you can hide the default close button and after that, you can add your own close button or any style

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dialogVisible: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
        beforeClose(done) {
        this.dialogVisible = false;
      done();
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-class {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.common.dev.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/2.13.2/index.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/element-ui/2.13.2/theme-chalk/index.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <el-button @click="dialogVisible = true">Click</el-button>
    <!-- <el-dialog :visible.sync="dialogVisible"> -->
    <el-dialog :visible="dialogVisible" :before-close="beforeClose" :show-close="false">
    <span class="my-class"><el-button type="danger" round  @click="dialogVisible = false">Close</el-button></span>
    
     
      <div slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
        <el-button @click="dialogVisible = false">Cancel</el-button>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="dialogVisible = false">Save</el-button>
      </div>
    </el-dialog>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Your css**

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I did just litle trick on it.

And here is the tricky way.

```
el-icon-close:before{
  content: "Close";
}
```

[codePen example](https://codepen.io/SomeOneOrAnyOne/pen/ExKdLzJ)